# Using two lists to compare elements and creating a list of non-same elements within those two lists?

Tags: python, list, indexing

So right now, I'm getting [3, 3, 3...] for 18 values, which is good because it means that my if and for loop are running well. The only issue is, I cant seem to figure out how to make the for loop skip over the non-same element.

'# This program compares two parallel lists to grade
'# a multiple choice exam. One list has the exam solution
'# and the second list has a student's answers.
'#
'# The question number of each missed question is stored
'# in a third list.

'# You must use the three lists provided in your solution.
'# Your solution must use indexing
'# Do not write any other user-defined functions
'#   - write all your code in the main function.
'# You may not embed Python programming statements inside list brackets [ ]

## main function

```
def main():

# do not modify this statement or contents of list
exam_solution = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
           'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']

# do not modify this statement or contents of list
student_answers = ['B', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C',\
           'D', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']

# do not modify this statement, you must begin with an empty list
questions_missed = []  

questions = int(len(exam_solution))
print(questions)
i= 0

for answers in range(0, questions):
    if exam_solution[i] == student_answers[i]:
        i += 1
    else:
        questions_missed.append(i+1)


print(questions_missed)



input('press enter to continue')   


main()
```

'## Your output should look like following:
'##
'##Congratulations!! You passed the exam

'##You answered 17 questions correctly and 3 questions incorrectly

'##The numbers of the questions you answered incorrectly are: 3 7 14

'##press enter to continue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if exam_solution[i] == student_answers[i]:
    i += 1
else:
    questions_missed.append(i+1)
```

should probably be

```
if exam_solution[answers] == student_answers[answers]:
    i += 1
else:
    questions_missed.append(answers + 1)
```

This is a good lesson in what happens when you don't select meaningful variable names

Comment: Such a simple fix that made the entire program work. Thank you so much.